# Django datatables.net

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django and jquery datatables.net.
My model has more than 13000 records.
When it starts, it shows a list as like datatables.net is not active while the columns are auto adjusting. After it finished to load all the records, the data takes 20sec to show with datatables.net active (works perfect) and shows the pagination and search cell. 
How should I make to only show the table from datatable.net and increase the speed?
Are there any way to show the first 10 records inmediatly?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**prutable.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, Table!</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
</head>    
<body>    
    <table id="table_id" class="display" border='2' align="center" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Importe</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>    
            {% for articulo in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ articulo.cdg }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.imp }}</td>
                <td>{{ articulo.stock }}</td>
            </tr>    
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>        
</body>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({    
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
class LstPreListView(ListView):
    template_name = "base/prutable.html"
    queryset = Articulo.objects.all().order_by("desc")
```

**models.py**

```
class Articulo(models.Model):   
    cdg = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, blank=True, null=False)
    desc = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    imp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} '.format(self.nombre)
```

Comment: Have you sloved this issue?

Comment: You have to initialise variable: